# Comando Java para ignorar Encoding

Tags: java, codificação-de-caracteres

Tenho a seguinte situação, trabalho com o software A de vendas de veículos, nele tem a oportunidade de venda e esta possui uma mídia (como o cliente ficou sabendo da oportunidade), além das oportunidades da loja o software A recebe informações de um site de veículos, este nos manda a informação de mídia com encoding diferente da mídia do software A, então esta é salva no banco com caracteres estranhos, *Indicação* ficaria algo do tipo: *IndicaÁ$Á&o*.

O site envia algo do tipo:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;  charset=utf-8");
```

...

```
$cliente = new client("http://999.999.999.999/WebService", false, $host, $porta, $usuario, $senha);

$chave_json = '[{ "chaveIntegracao" : "var1_",
    "valor" : "'.$_POST["var1"].'"},
        {"chaveIntegracao" : "var2_",
        "valor" : "'.$_POST["var2"].'"},
        {"chaveIntegracao" : "var3_",
        "valor" : "'.$_POST["var3"].'"},
        {"chaveIntegracao" : "var4_",
        "valor" : "'.$_POST["var4"].'"
      }]';

$dados[interfaceJson] = $chave_json;         

$result = $cliente->call('criarEvento', $dados, 'http://.../', 'http://.../');
```

Tem alguma forma de pegar o código estranho e converter, sem precisar tratar cada possibilidade de caractere estranho ?

```
//transforma qualquer encoding em UTF-8
CastEncoding(vo.getMidia(),"UTF-8");
```

Comment: Como você está lendo as informações que chegam desse site externo? Elas estão chegando como byte ou como string? Idealmente, esse tipo de coisa tem que ser feito na chegada, antes dos bytes virarem string. Depois que virou, seria um inferno pra desfazer... Por favor poste o trecho de código que lê essa entrada (imagino que você deve estar criando um `Reader` em algum lugar sem especificar o *encoding*, estou certo?).

Comment: Relacionado: ["O Mínimo Absoluto Que Todo Desenvolvedor De Software Absolutamente, Positivamente Precisa Saber Sobre Unicode E Conjuntos de Caracteres (Sem Desculpas!)"](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todo_Desenvolvedor_De_Software_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_Precisa_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_E_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_%28Sem_Desculpas!%29)

Comment: @mgibsonbr O site envia um JSON com a informação, mas vou pedir para eles corrigirem isto, depois vou fazer um UPDATE no banco, não tenho muita escolha, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Blz, mas como você pega esse JSON? Como é o código Java que lê isso? Mesmo se eles não corrigirem do lado deles, você ainda consegue pegar os dados certos se você souber qual é o *encoding* desse JSON.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Esta a integração não é comigo, só trabalho com os dados integrados, vou me informar melhor e te dou retorno.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Atualizei a pergunta, esta é a informação que o site nos manda, recebemos com Web Service.

Comment: Você tem certeza que o erro está no lado deles? Eu acho que o erro está no seu lado, mas se você não mostrar o seu código Java não tem como eu te ajudar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Comando Java para ignorar Encoding

Não é assim que a banda toca, o encoding é necessario para resolver como os bits do texto serão interpretados.

---

> O site envia algo do tipo:
>
> ```
> header("Content-Type: text/html;  charset=utf-8");
> ```

Isso significa que o site esta informando que o seu conteúdo esta utilizando o charset UTF-8, mas você precisa verificar primeiro se os arquivos do PHP são UTF-8, caso o contrario não vai funcionar.

Comment: foi identificado que o encoding dos dados enviados pelo cliente era WINDOWS-1251, neste caso após a correção no lado do cliente, será feito um update nos dados incorretos no banco.